# Ember.js: extract queryParams object

Tags: ember.js, query-string

I'm using Ember's queryParams:
http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/query-params/

The query params are dynamic, so the base controller does not know what the properties will be.  E.g. it can be `['q', 'page']` or `['q', 'foo', 'bar']` or any other permutation.

How can I get the parameter object of the query params so that I can pass it in to `store.find('modelName', params)` without knowing what the actual query param attributes are?

One way to do it would be the following inside the controller:

```
var params = {};
this.get('queryParams').forEach(function(param){
  params[param] = this.get(param);
}, this);

this.store.find('widget', params);
```

...but there must be a more elegant way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is any better, but what I currently do is the following:

`this.store.find('widget',
   this.getProperties(this.getProperties('queryParams').queryParams)
)`

This will take all query params on the controller and provide them to the model.find method. I am not sure if there are negative ramifications to this approach, but it is a little more succinct than iterating over each property.